# Is all web hosting servers support rewrite engine in apache?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am new to Codeigniter.
Now i developed one project in codeigniter and **i want to live it soon**...
That is not a matter but while i started to develop the site i were want to remove **index.php** from the url of codeigniter. For that i need to write formula in .htaccess to **mod rewrite** apache engine. **I have enabled mod rewrite engine mode on my local server manually**.
It was worked and i was **developed the project**.But
When i goes to live i having doubt, **Is all web hosting servers are allows mod rewrite apache engine or not?**
If not how can i live my site??
Can anyone ans my quistion to help me????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mod_rewrite` is usually enabled but it's good to confirm it. If the live server is running Apache the loaded modules can be determined with the PHP function `apache_get_modules()`.

Create a simple controller - Mod_test.php

```
class Mod_test extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
         var_dump(apache_get_modules());
    }
}
```

Upload the file to the live server (in the controllers folder) and direct the browser to

```
http://yoursite.com/index.php/mod_test
```

Look for the string 'mod_rewrite' in the resulting output.

If it isn't there you should contact the host provider to see if the mod can be enabled.

Be sure to delete this controller when you have got your answer.